# How to hide div a when toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used checkbox as toggle menu with the help of css. But now i have to hide a div when toggled. How can it be done.

```css
/*------- Toggle switch --------*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #20c000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 44px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Transition */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="togg-switch-btn">
  <label class="switch">
                                                    <input class="switch-input slide-toggle" type="checkbox" />
                                                    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
                                                    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
                                                </label>
</div>


<!-- Hiding Div -->
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
  <p align="end">Completed Date : <span style="color:#c54d2d;">27-05-2017</span></p>
  <p align="end" style="color:#c54d2d;">John Jose</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this you want

```js
$("#cbox").change(function() {
  $("#myDiv").toggle();
});
```

```css
/*------- Toggle switch --------*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #20c000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 44px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Transition */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="togg-switch-btn">
  <label class="switch">
                                                    <input class="switch-input slide-toggle" type="checkbox" id="cbox" />
                                                    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
                                                    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
                                                </label>
</div>


<!-- Hiding Div -->
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="myDiv">
  <p align="end">Completed Date : <span style="color:#c54d2d;">27-05-2017</span></p>
  <p align="end" style="color:#c54d2d;">John Jose</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Accept answer if you got your result

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with solution https://jsfiddle.net/7sx5tavx/

```js
$('.switch-input').change(function() {
  $('.col-md-8').toggle();
});
```

```css
/*------- Toggle switch --------*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #20c000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 44px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Transition */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="togg-switch-btn">
  <label class="switch">
        <input class="switch-input slide-toggle" type="checkbox" />
        <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
        <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
    </label>
</div>


<!-- Hiding Div -->
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
  <p align="end">Completed Date : <span style="color:#c54d2d;">27-05-2017</span></p>
  <p align="end" style="color:#c54d2d;">John Jose</p>

</div>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = document.querySelector('.x');

let checkbox = document.querySelector('.switch-input');


checkbox.onclick = () => {
    x.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
/*------- Toggle switch --------*/

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
    border-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #bfbfbf;
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-transition: inherit;
    -moz-transition: inherit;
    -o-transition: inherit;
    transition: inherit;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
    content: attr(data-off);
    right: 11px;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
    content: attr(data-on);
    left: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
    background: #20c000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
    opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
    left: 44px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Transition */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
    transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}


.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="togg-switch-btn">
        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input slide-toggle" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
            <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>
    </div>


    <!-- Hiding Div -->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 x">
        <p align="end">Completed Date : <span style="color:#c54d2d;">27-05-2017</span></p>
        <p align="end" style="color:#c54d2d;">John Jose</p>

    </div>
```

---

another solution

```js
let x = document.querySelector('.x');

let checkbox = document.querySelector('.switch-input');


checkbox.onclick = () => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (!checkbox.checked) {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
/*------- Toggle switch --------*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #20c000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 44px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Transition */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="togg-switch-btn">
  <label class="switch">
                                                    <input class="switch-input slide-toggle" type="checkbox" />
                                                    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
                                                    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
                                                </label>
</div>


<!-- Hiding Div -->
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 x">
  <p align="end">Completed Date : <span style="color:#c54d2d;">27-05-2017</span></p>
  <p align="end" style="color:#c54d2d;">John Jose</p>

</div>
```

added a class name x to the element to hide